# Flutter Riverpod: How to trigger FutureProvider after first execution fail?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Is there any way to retry a FutureProvider when the first attempt fails?

The provider:

```
final _dataProvider = FutureProvider((ref) => ref.watch(productRepositoryProvider).fetchProducts());
```

The consumer:

```
return watch(_dataProvider).when(
  data: (value) {
    return Text('Ok');
  },
  loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
  error: (error, stackTrace) {    
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Retry'),
      onPressed: () {
        // What should I add here to retry this FutureProvider?
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to call watch(_dataprovider) in your onPressed?

Comment: Actually, you can't use `watch` outside of the body of a `Consumer`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try

```
onPressed: () {
        context.refresh(_dataProvider);
      },
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It should be done with the `WidgetRef` object by calling `ref.refresh(_dataProvider)`.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are outdated. Instead use:

```
ref.invalidate(yourProvider);
```

From the definition:
'Invalidates the state of the provider, causing it to refresh.

As opposed to [refresh], the refresh is not immediate and is instead delayed to the next read or next frame.

Calling [invalidate] multiple times will refresh the provider only once.

Calling [invalidate] will cause the provider to be disposed immediately.

If used on a provider which is not initialized, this method will have no effect. '

Make sure that you call this in the same ProviderScope as your provider!

Comment: did you mean "Calling _[refresh]_ multiple times will refresh the provider only once." ?

Comment: From what i understand, refresh is invalidate but it also immediately recalculates the value and returns it. So if you’re not using the new value, call invalidate.

Note that if you’re watching the value somewhere, it will ‘refresh’ when calling invalidate.

Answer (score 3):

i think that the most proper approach for what  you are trying to do is something like this :

**StreamProvider and Autodispose**

```
final productRepositoryProvider =
    Provider<IProductRepository>((ref) => ProductRepository());

final allProductProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<ProductModel>>((ref) {
  final _productRepository = ref.watch(productRepositoryProvider);
  return _productRepository.allProductsStream;
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Wherever, I accepted the other answer because it target specifically what was mentioned on the question (FutureProvider). But I updated my code to use StreamProvider. Many thanks!

Comment: no worries , glad that i helped, hope u find mine useful , happy coding !

Comment: How to refresh the repository?

Answer (score 1):

ref.invalidate(provider);

ref.read(provider);